# What is the correct way of using preparedStatements in Java to send data to a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want send the String "Gulliver's Travels" to a sql database from a java application. I tried using preparedStatements but failed. How can I do this?
Here is my code.

```
private int setData(Connection conn,Object[] data){
     String sql = "INSERT INTO book VALUES(?,?)";
     PreparedStatement prepStm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     prepStm.setObject(1,data[0]);
     prepStm.setObject(2,data[1]);
     return prepStm.executeUpdate();
}
```

table columns :

```
    bookName : VARCHAR
    bookPrice : INT
```

Error :
        SQL Syntax error. Fails to add the name field to the database

Comment: What columns are available in `book`?  What types are they?

Comment: bookName - VARCHAR
bookPrice - VARCHAR

gives a SQL syntax error. the bookName column is not filled.

Comment: Don't forget to close the `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this
This is for the updated question

```
private int setData(Connection conn,Object[] data){
     String sql = "INSERT INTO book VALUES(?,?)";
     PreparedStatement prepStm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     prepStm.setString(1,"Gulliver's Travels");
     prepStm.setInt(2,200);
     return prepStm.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Wait. I'll try.. By the way can anyone tell me why my question is voted down?

Comment: @isuru-buddhika improve your question by giving more information.See the comments in your question.Many  users wants more details

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I actually didnt thought tables columns will be a problem. By the way why I cannot use prepStm.setObject ?

Comment: @isuru-buddhika table columns are also important because see when you are inserting using command line,you write insert into tablename values(1,'string') means if the column is varchar then you pass with in ''.The same thing you have to do in JDBC too

Comment: I got it now. SO if I use setObject it want work properly is that so?

Comment: @isuru-buddhika if my answer is useful to you then you can accept it and about your query for setobject ,post another question for the same

Answer (score 1):

If your column types are VARCHAR in the actual database table, then use

```
 prepStm.setString(1,"Gulliver's Travels");
```

instead of

```
 prepStm.setObject(1,"Gulliver's Travels");
```

Follow this tutorial to learn more about PreparedStatement and its usage.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0):

Setting an object is not what you are supposed to be doing. When you know the data type of the input as well as the data type of the database column, then use the correct setter methods.

```
private int setData(Connection conn,Object[] data){
     String sql = "INSERT INTO book VALUES(?,?)";
     PreparedStatement prepStm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     prepStm.setString(1,"Gulliver's Travels");
     prepStm.setFloat(2,200.00);
     return prepStm.executeUpdate();
}
```